# Does List<T>.ToList() enumerate the collection

Tags: c#, icollection

Through the travels in StackOverflow there are many usages of the `ToList()` extension method for an `ICollection` (or classes that derive from `ICollection<T>`).

I have pulled out the good ol' decompiler to have a look at how the `ToList()` extension method is executed and does it enumerate the collection at anytime. Going through the source I came across:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

Now this is pretty straight forward, so the `ToList()` extension method just creates a new `List<T>` with the source object. Digging deeper into the List constructor shows this line.

```
ICollection<T> ts = collection as ICollection<T>;
//.. ommited code
ts.CopyTo(this._items, 0);
```

As you would, you would dig into the `CopyTo` method. This is where I got stuck. After all the digging through method calls we get to the final `extern` method call

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.MayCorruptInstance, Cer.MayFail)]
[SecurityCritical]
internal static extern void Copy(Array sourceArray, int sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, int destinationIndex, int length, bool reliable);
```

My question is (although I cant seem to find it) does the `ToList()` extension method (`ICollection<T>.CopyTo()`) iterate through all objects of the Collection (Array) when executed?

Subquestion: Where can I find the source for the `extern void Copy()` above?

**Edit:** I have edited the question directly as I realized after that I am trying to get a specification on an Interface and not implementation. Sorry

Comment: I think I may need to rephrase the question as it should be talking specifically about the ToList() function..

Comment: I've updated my answer a little bit to make the point, because it's really important what you're calling `ToList()` on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> My question is (although I cant seem to find it) does the `ToList()`
>   extension method `(ICollection<T>.CopyTo())` iterate through all
>   objects of the Collection (`Array`) when executed?

**No, it does not.** It just copies the underlying array storage using `Array.Copy`.

---

***Update***

Just to make sure my answer is interpreted correctly. **`ToList()` does not enumerate the source collection when it's being called directly on another `List<T>` or `T[]` array** (or other collection which implements `ICollection.CopyTo` without enumerator).

When you call `ToList<>` e.g. on `Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).ToList()` there will be an enumeration. Enumeration will be also performed when you use any LINQ method, e.g. `myList.Select(x => x.PropertyName).ToList()` will cause enumeration.

***End of update***

---

```
void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int arrayIndex)
{
    if (array != null && array.Rank != 1)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Arg_RankMultiDimNotSupported);
    }
    try
    {
        Array.Copy(this._items, 0, array, arrayIndex, this._size);
    }
    catch (ArrayTypeMismatchException)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Argument_InvalidArrayType);
    }
}
```

which uses unmanaged c++ code to do that in efficient way:

> This method is equivalent to the standard C/C++ function `memmove`, not `memcpy.`
>
> from [`Array.Copy` Method (Array, Array, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 C/C++ function memmove, not memcpy. Array.Copy Method (Array, Array, Int32)

Comment: I understand a block copy is going to be more efficient than enumeration, but isnt it still an O(n) operation? It definitely has to be for a collection of value types (e.g. `List<int>().ToList()`), isnt it? Because each value has to be copied. But even for reference types, `memmove` has to be O(n) right?

Answer (score 1):

> does the ToList() extension method (ICollection.CopyTo()) iterate through all objects of the Collection

It depends on how `ICollection<T>` is implemented in particular class.

For example, `List<T>` implementation just copies array (without iteration), because internally `List<T>` uses array as a storage. But nothing prevents you (or someone else) to write implementation, which will iterate though the source collection.

> Where can I find the source for the extern void Copy() above

methods, marked by `MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)`, are implemented in unmanaged C++ code. I'm not sure, that there are any opened sources for them. But I suppose, that, ultimately, there's something like `memcpy(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

**extern** it means that function will be implemented in outside of C# code. It could be implemented in C/C++. More detail :

> [extern keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx)

Comment: I understand what the keyword `extern` means, what I am insterested in knowing is where can I locate the source file. I also cant seem to find which external code is being loaded from.

Comment: oh I see, let's this guy @Hans Passant . I don't know how to invite him to answer you :)